# mod_rewrite: Redirect sub-domain and folders, but not folder contents

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have assets.domain.com hosting all my images, typefaces, scripts, etc. for a Wordpress installation on the top-level domain. I want to redirect any access to subdomain and folders to top-level domain without affecting the folder contents (lots of file types, so would like to avoid having to list each one as an exemption but if that's my only choice, so be it).

Got close with:

```
# Enable URL Rewriting
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(images|type|scripts)(/.*|$) - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/robots.txt
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !images/.* [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !type/.* [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !scripts/.* [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.domain\.com [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks to [Christopher Brix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168307/mod-rewrite-but-skip-a-directory) and [mootinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717637/htaccess-mod-rewrite-exemptions).

Comment: What is not working with the solution you currently have?

Comment: It's not redirecting folders. Just the base sub-domain.

Comment: But maybe I'm being anal? I dropped the .htaccess file in the sub-folders and that didn't do anything.